# regexp include null in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex

Is it possible to do the following in mysql with a single where clause?

```
WHERE
    employer IS NULL 
 OR employer REGEXP 'employed|indepdendent|self|freelanc'
```

That is, move the `NULL` into the regexp?

Comment: Regex only checks strings, it can't check other values. Unless you coerce NULL to a `'NULL'` string of course.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case that gives rise to this requirement to include checking for `NULL` using RegExp (which, as @WiktorStribiżew points out, generally wouldn't work without coercing it to a string value)?

Comment: @esqew it's just how the data is stored. Sometimes it's `null`, sometimes empty string, sometimes some values that "mean null", etc.

Comment: @David542 Makes sense, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Are the values in employer *just* the strings employed, indepdendent, self and freelanc or are those just words included in them e.g. 'mostly indepdendent`?

Comment: @Nick well the employer should be something like "Facebook" or "General Motors", so if they have something that basically means "Not employed by a specific company" I want to treat it as null.

Comment: So in that case though would it just be the word employed, indepdendent, self or freelanc?

Comment: Yea, those are some keywords I want to filter out. Someone having something like "Freelance" or "Freelancer" or "Self-Employed", etc.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment by @Wiktor, the simplest way to do this would be to coerce the field to a string so that the regex can work against a non-null string value.

For example:

```
WHERE
    COALESCE(employer, 'NULL') REGEXP 'employed|indepdendent|self|null|freelanc'
```

Comment: I agree that this is likely the best way to do it if you *must* reduce to a single `where` clause, but I disagree with the premise that doing this is a good thing. I've had data that included the literal `"NULL"` string, so to me this technique would have masked that problem. Additionally, the regex you've chosen can over-match when any substring of `employer` contains `'self'` or `'null'`. If you are certain that it will never happen, that's fine ... but it never happens until it does. (Somebody specializing in "jury nullification", perhaps?)

Comment: @r2evans ha, jury nullification or any self services -- self help, self-guided...good point, agreed!